# Why use `sigsetjmp` instead of `setjmp` function in C?

Tags: c, signals

Why might somebody choose to use `sigsetjmp` instead of `setjmp` in C?

I read in a book that there are some disadvantages in using `setjmp` with signal-related code, so the `sigsetjmp` function was implemented.

Can anybody explain this with an example?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The problem is clearly specified, and also the answer is enough objective to exist on the site. I suggest **reopen**.

Answer (score 23):

See [section 10.15 in “Advanced Programming in the UNIX® Environment”](http://poincare.matf.bg.ac.rs/%7Eivana/courses/tos/sistemi_knjige/pomocno/apue/APUE/0201433079/ch10lev1sec15.html):

> the setjmp and longjmp functions, which can be used for nonlocal
> branching. The longjmp function is often called from a signal handler
> to return to the main loop of a program, instead of returning from the
> handler. We saw this in Figures 10.8 and 10.11.
>
> There is a problem in calling longjmp, however. When a signal is
> caught, the signal-catching function is entered with the current
> signal automatically being added to the signal mask of the process.
> This prevents subsequent occurrences of that signal from interrupting
> the signal handler. If we longjmp out of the signal handler, what
> happens to the signal mask for the process?
>
> Under FreeBSD 5.2.1 and Mac OS X 10.3, setjmp and longjmp save and restore the signal mask. Linux 2.4.22 and Solaris 9, however, do not
> do this. FreeBSD and Mac OS X provide the functions _setjmp and
> _longjmp, which do not save and restore the signal mask.
>
> To allow either form of behavior, POSIX.1 does not specify the effect
> of setjmp and longjmp on signal masks. Instead, two new functions,
> sigsetjmp and siglongjmp, are defined by POSIX.1. These two functions
> should always be used when branching from a signal handler.
>
> ...
>
> The only difference between these functions and the setjmp and longjmp
> functions is that sigsetjmp has an additional argument. If savemask is
> nonzero, then sigsetjmp also saves the current signal mask of the
> process in env. When siglongjmp is called, if the env argument was
> saved by a call to sigsetjmp with a nonzero savemask, then siglongjmp
> restores the saved signal mask.