# Returning from a signal handler via setcontext

Tags: c, linux, assembly, signals, x86-64

I'm trying to use the third argument of a `SA_SIGINFO sigaction` to jump to the interrupted context directly.

Thought this:

```c
void action(int Sig, siginfo_t *Info, void *Uctx) { 
    ucontext_t *uc = Uctx; setcontext(uc); 
}
```

would have the same effect as just:

```c
void action(int Sig, siginfo_t *Info, void *Uctx) { 
    return; 
}
```

but curiously it accepts three signals (that invoke the setcontext-calling handler), and then it segfaults
in `setcontext`:

```
Dump of assembler code for function setcontext:
   0x00007ffff7a34180 <+0>:     push   %rdi
   0x00007ffff7a34181 <+1>:     lea    0x128(%rdi),%rsi
   0x00007ffff7a34188 <+8>:     xor    %edx,%edx
   0x00007ffff7a3418a <+10>:    mov    $0x2,%edi
   0x00007ffff7a3418f <+15>:    mov    $0x8,%r10d
   0x00007ffff7a34195 <+21>:    mov    $0xe,%eax
   0x00007ffff7a3419a <+26>:    syscall
   0x00007ffff7a3419c <+28>:    pop    %rdi
   0x00007ffff7a3419d <+29>:    cmp    $0xfffffffffffff001,%rax
   0x00007ffff7a341a3 <+35>:    jae    0x7ffff7a34200 <setcontext+128>
   0x00007ffff7a341a5 <+37>:    mov    0xe0(%rdi),%rcx
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
   0x00007ffff7a341ac <+44>:    fldenv (%rcx)
=> 0x00007ffff7a341ae <+46>:    ldmxcsr 0x1c0(%rdi)
   0x00007ffff7a341b5 <+53>:    mov    0xa0(%rdi),%rsp
   0x00007ffff7a341bc <+60>:    mov    0x80(%rdi),%rbx
```

and the fault address shown by strace is 0 (a catchable SIGSEGV).

Here's an example program that's using a timer to send the three signals:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <ucontext.h>
#include <signal.h>
  
void action(int Sig, siginfo_t *Info, void *Uctx) { 
    ucontext_t *uc = Uctx; setcontext(uc); 
}
int main(void) {
    char ch[100];
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &(struct sigaction){.sa_sigaction = action, .sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO}, 0);
    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &(struct itimerval){.it_interval.tv_sec = 1,.it_value.tv_sec = 1}, 0);
    write(1, "enter\n", 6);
    for (;;) {
        write(1, "{\n", 2);
        read(0, &ch[0], sizeof(ch));
        write(1, "}\n", 2);
    }
}
```

What is going on in this situation?

Comment: FWIW, the only success I've ever had returning from a signal handler like this is with [`sigsetjmp()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigsetjmp.html)and [`siglongjmp()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigsetjmp.html)  This is probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755260/why-use-sigsetjmp-instead-of-setjmp-function-in-c

Comment: Interesting.  I can reproduce this on Linux amd64, but not with -m32 or with arm64.  The segfault is in `setcontext` when it tries to `ldmxcsr` with a possibly invalid value.

Comment: And if I replace the loop body with `stmxcsr` in a loop, the value doesn't match what the handler sees in `uc->__fpregs_mem.mxcsr`, and changes when the context is restored.  It seems like the `mxcsr` value in the `*uc` struct isn't correct and sometimes isn't valid (has some of bits 16-31 set).  Not sure if it's supposed to be correct at this point.

Comment: What's a bit odd is that `uc->uc_mcontext.fpregs` seems to point to a correctly populated `_libc_fpstate`, including the correct value of `mxcsr`.  However `setcontext` loads `mxcsr` not from there, but from `uc->__fpregs_mem.mxcsr`.  And `.fpregs` points **within** `.__fpregs_mem`, 24 bytes in.  That seems weird.  It's not the way `getcontext` would set it up, I don't think.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like libc thinks the fpregs are contained within `struct ucontext_t` itself, while the kernel puts them as a separate structure on the stack, with a pointer to it in `uc->uc_mcontext.fpregs`.  It's unclear if that mismatch is a bug, or if they are just never meant to be the same.

Comment: Oh, the source for glibc's `setcontext` says it is to be used for synchronous context switches only; it doesn't restore the entire machine state (for instance it doesn't restore any of the xmm registers, and it zeroes rax).  So it seems that it's just totally unsuitable to try to `setcontext` to the context you got in a signal handler.

Comment: Re: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71751036/returning-from-a-signal-handler-without-going-the-kernel-userspace-interrupts which you deleted after Jester pointed out `ret 128` could jump and pop the stack:  
Will it confuse the kernel if you never call `sigreturn`?  e.g. affecting delivery of future signals because it thinks you're still inside a signal handler.  Or would that only be a problem if you'd used `sigaltstack` and installed the handler with `SA_ONSTACK`?

Comment: @PeterCordes Undeleted it (first felt it was a stupid question, but then perhaps not so much -- I'm still interested in how these assembly-level things will work with userspace interrupts). It should not confuse the kernel AFAIK. AFAIK, the kernel doesn't expect each signal delivery to be paired with sigreturn. It's well valid (POSIX-sanctioned, even) to siglongjmp from a signal handler when it interrupted async-signal-safe code. In that case sigreturn won't run either.

Comment: @PeterCordes: My understanding is that the only way in which signal handling affects future signals is that it changes the signal mask: the signal being delivered is blocked (unless `SA_NODEFER` was used) together with any others in the mask passed to `sigaction`.  So if you want to go directly back to your program without `sigreturn`, the only consequence is that the signal mask may not be what the main program had, but you can use `sigprocmask` to change it back.  Which is exactly what `siglongjmp` does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is something that's simply not meant to work: you are only supposed to call `setcontext` with a context obtained from `getcontext` or `makecontext`, and not with the context passed to a signal handler.

[The man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setcontext) hints at this obliquely:

> If the context was obtained by a call to a signal handler, then old standard text says that "program execution continues with the program instruction following the instruction interrupted by the signal". However, this sentence was removed in SUSv2, and the present verdict is "the result is unspecified".

Also, [the glibc source of `setcontext`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/setcontext.S;h=b071fd9fd05650b47b98f418e2ea51e2c2aa834a;hb=HEAD#l30) has a comment:

> This implementation is intended to be used for *synchronous* context
> switches only.  Therefore, it does not have to restore anything
> other than the PRESERVED state.

Indeed, it does not attempt to restore any of the floating-point registers, and it zeroes `rax` (as for `getcontext` returning 0).  That would be pretty bad for trying to resume code that isn't expecting its registers to change spontaneously.

Asynchronous context switching would be needed for something like preemptive multitasking in userspace.  I think the idea is that since pthreads is now firmly established, people should have no need for this, so it's not supported.  `getcontext/setcontext` date from an earlier era, and in fact have since been removed from the POSIX spec on the premise that pthreads should be used instead.

---

This particular crash seems to be caused by a mismatch between the kernel's layout of `struct ucontext_t`, and what libc expects.  In particular, libc expects the floating-point state, including the saved value of `mxcsr`, at a particular offset within `struct ucontext_t`.  However the kernel pushes the floating point state at a separate location on the stack (which happens to overlap where libc expects it), and includes a pointer to it inside `struct ucontext_t`.  So libc's `setcontext` attempts to load some garbage value into `mxcsr`, which has some of the reserved bits 16-31 set, and this causes a general protection fault.

However, as noted above, this mismatch is the least of the problems.