# Returning from a signal handler without going the kernel + userspace interrupts

Tags: linux, assembly, signals, x86-64, interrupt

This is a followup on my older question: [Returning from a signal handler via setcontext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69237910/returning-from-a-signal-handler-via-setcontext)

I tried to write the assembly for doing the context switch from a signal handler back to the interrupted context without the kernel assist (the sigreturn system call) for a signal handler where blocked signals don't need to be changed (`SA_NODEFER`).

It seems doable (mostly just reloading registers) up to a final point: setting `%rsp` and `%rip` back.
From what I understand, if there was *no red zone*, I could do something like:

```
 //use %rax to old %rsp, and %rcx as a scratch register
 mov RSP_OFFSET(%rdi), %rax
 // push old rip, rax, rcx, rdi using the scratch %rcx register
 mov RIP_OFFSET(%rdi), %rcx
 mov %rcx, -8(%rax)
 mov RAX_OFFSET(%rdi), %rcx
 mov %rcx, -16(%rax)
 mov RCX_OFFSET(%rdi), %rcx
 mov %rcx, -24(%rax)
 mov RDI_OFFSET(%rdi), %rcx
 mov %rcx, -32(%rax)
 //make rax point to old_rsp - 32
 lea -32(%rax), %rax
 mov %rax, %rsp //restore rsp to that
 //restore the pushed registers through actual popping
 pop %rdi
 pop %rcx
 pop %rax
 //pop and set %rip
 ret
```

but with the redzone it seems impossible as there's (?) no way to atomically (with respect to signals)  and without register use pop off a large amount from the stack and jump to an address stored deep in the popped off portion (or somewhere completely different as is the case with alternate signal stacks). I looked at hardware task switching but that is unsupported in 64-bit protected mode.

How will this work with the upcoming user-level interrupts? Will those handlers be able to somehow return without going through the kernel?

Comment: Put `rip` under the red zone, point `rsp` there (actually move `rsp` first) then use `ret X` with the appropriate `X` (128 probably).

Comment: @Jester Thank you very much! Didn't know you could do that with ret

Comment: Found the answer for how user interrupts are delivered and returned from in https://www.intel.com/content/dam/develop/external/us/en/documents/architecture-instruction-set-extensions-programming-reference.pdf and https://lwn.net/Articles/869140/